# Is there really a use for trigonometry in cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, trigonometry, encryption

So I'm reading this book on an introduction to cryptography, there's this exercise about reading a message from a paper and you'd have to use a cosine function to find out how many letters each strip of paper should have (once you tear it, so you could decode the message).

I mean really? Will there be a similar scenario to this? whats the use? Or are there other applications of trigonometry in cryptography?

Comment: Actual cryptography uses much more complicated maths than simple trigonometry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography

Comment: @pedrosorio yeah but it uses trigonometry?

Comment: Any maths that is simple to compute but hard to reverse (like multiplication vs. factoring) can be used in crypto.

Comment: I can't see a reason to use trigonomy in cryptography. Modern cryptography almost exclusively works with integers, not real numbers.

Comment: @vincentbelkin: no, modern cryptography exploits mathematical problem that are "one-way hard" such as: multiplication VS factorization of large numbers, discrete logarithm VS inverse discrete logarithm. Trigonometry is "one-way hard" too but only in a world without computers. For "one-way hard" I mean a problem which is solvable in polinomial time (easy) in one direction (e.g. multiplication) and solvable in exponential time (hard) in the other direction (e.g. factorization).

Comment: Tearing papers isn't used in modern crypto, and trigonomy might be inherent in the geometric properties your classical algorithm uses. So trigometry seems to be an artifact of your specific classical algorithm, and not the main point of it.

Comment: I you found a useful discrete implementation of trigonometry, maybe it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function/method that implements the properties of [diffusion and confusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion) (cit. Shannon) is eligible to be used for cryptographic purpose

However, diffusion and confusion are relative to the computational power of the system in which the algorithm will run. For the average guy with paper&pencil trigonometric functions will suffice, for modern CPUs more complicated math should be used (factorization of large numbers, inversion of discrete logarithms, math over elliptic curve etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the idea behind functions used in cryptography, is that they should produce a result that is as complex as possible, without taking up too many resources when running. Trigonometric functions produce results that is hard to reverse into its original source, so they are examples of functions that serve a purpose in cryptography.

Whether they're used in any actual crypto algorithms i cannot say for sure, other than my immediate thought: "probably". They work, so why would people avoid it? It's pretty much up to whoever is making the algorithm.

Comment: Most trigonometric functions are easily reversed.